# Put request with file and json body

Tags: java, rest, postman, put

I create a POST Rest API with @RequestParam and it works with :

```
@PostMapping("/shop-menu")
@PreAuthorize("@accessChecker.hasAccessToWebservice(#request)")
public ResponseEntity<EntiteShopMenuDTO> addShopMenu(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                       @RequestParam("numeroLicence") String numeroLicence,
                                                       @RequestParam("ordre") Integer ordre,
                                                       @RequestParam("titre") String titre,
                                                       @RequestParam("url") String url,
                                                       @RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile logo) throws URISyntaxException, CustomException, IOException {
```

and I use Postman for test :

[image]

That works fine.

Now I want the same thing but PUT Request :

```
@PutMapping("/shop-menu/{numeroLicence}")
@PreAuthorize("@accessChecker.hasAccessToWebservice(#request)")
public ResponseEntity<EntiteShopMenuDTO> updateShopMenu(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                          @PathVariable String numeroLicence,
                                                          @RequestParam("test") String test,
                                                         @RequestParam(value = "logoFile", required = false) MultipartFile logoFile) throws CustomException, IOException {
```

And with Postman to try :

[image]

And result is :

```
{
"type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": 400,
"detail": "Required String parameter 'test' is not present",
"path": "/api/shop-menu/BJ3-M1",
"message": "error.http.400"
}
```

I try the same thing with json body for object param instead of test param, and same result.

With Curl it works  :

```
curl -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer <MY_TOKEN>' {"type":"formData"} 'http://localhost:8080/api/shop-menu/BJ3-M1?test=TOTO'
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Check that you don"t have extra spaces around the `test` key.

Comment: @Arnaud no spaces ;)

Comment: Also try to pass this parameter in the 'Params" tab of Postman instead of the "Body" tab.

Comment: Just for confirmation, are you sure first one is working fine? Try giving the 'test' parameter in 'Params' tab (left most) in postman and see if it works?

Comment: @Arnaud it works fine with Params tab. And if I want to send json body, an idea?

Comment: For a JSON in the body, indeed use the "Body" tab (type = raw, not form-data), and annotate the parameter with `@RequestBody` in your method.

Comment: I try with @RequestBody and my param contain my json data, but result is : "title": "Unsupported Media Type", "status": 415,

Comment: Consider adding a key : `content-type` value : `application/json` header to your Postman request.

Comment: Sorry but same result :(

Comment: I will use several params and not json body and it works. Thanks for your help @Arnaud